SQL Oracle - SUBQUERY to selectively pull data from *different* column, depending on table conditions
Jumping straight in. We have tables (TABLE) and audit tables (AUDITTABLE) that store changes to the main table.
In the table, we have entries like:



ID
Name
Created
LocationID
PersonID




1
Utah
01/01/94
35
1


2
Ohio
02/01/95
42
5



Changing the LocationID of row #1 from 35 to 50, and PersonID from 1 to 3 would be recorded in the audit table like (omitting some columns for brevity, there are also items like created and createdby to track when and by whom a value was changed):



ID
SourceID
Key
OldValue




1
1
LOCATIONID
35


2
1
PERSONID
1



I am writing a query where I am pulling data from the audit table:
SELECT
    sourceid AS ID,
    id AS EVENT_ID
    key AS COLUMN,
    oldvalue AS PREVIOUS_ENTRY
FROM
    AUDITTABLE

I want a sub-query within the select that pulls the currently stored value within the main table, depending upon the KEY from the audit table (which matches the main table column names one-for-one) for the current row.  I can do this with a Case statement, but I have about 100 tables to do this for with each one having unique column names (and multiple dozens of columns each), which would be a nightmare to write.
EDIT
I'm looking at the recommended articles after writing this, and it seems like everything is pointing to writing case statements.  If that's ultimately the answer, please just let me know this isn't doable in the manner I need, and no need to waste your time writing example case statements or unioned queries--that's well within my skillset, despite the physical agony that will ensue
I was thinking something like the below (which obviously doesn't work, but shows the general idea of what I'm trying to achieve).
SELECT
    sourceid AS ID,
    id AS EVENT_ID
    key AS COLUMN,
    oldvalue AS PREVIOUS_ENTRY,
    (SELECT TABLE. || (SELECT TEMPAUDITTABLE.KEY 
                       FROM AUDITTABLE AS TEMPAUDITTABLE 
                       WHERE TEMPAUDITTABLE.SOURCEID = AUDITTABLE.SOURCEID) 
     FROM Table 
     WHERE Table.ID = Audittable.sourceid) AS Current_Value
FROM
    AUDITTABLE

I know you can get table column names from USER_TAB_COLUMNS which may be part of the solution, but I have no idea how to implement something like that.
I apologize in advance if I'm missing something obvious. I'm fairly decent at writing queries, but I'm about 90% self-taught and there are likely some gaps in my knowledge.
To anyone willing to help point me in the right direction, thank you!
I've tried google, copilot, tech-on-the-net, and searching through stack overflow questions. I've also referenced the documentation for SQL Oracle.

You can use an XML trick to generate and run the dymamic SQL as part of a plain query, without your own PL/SQL function.
If you add a call to
DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE ('select "' || key || '" from table1 where id = ' || sourceid)

to your query it will give you the current value; but as part of an XML document. So you can use XMLQuery or XMLTable to extract it; this uses that expanded query as a CTE:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        sourceid AS ID,
        id AS EVENT_ID,
        key AS COLUMN_NAME,
        oldvalue AS PREVIOUS_ENTRY,
        DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE (
            'select "' || key || '" from table1 where id = ' || sourceid) AS XML
    FROM
        AUDITTABLE
)
SELECT
    ID,
    EVENT_ID,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    PREVIOUS_ENTRY,
    CURRENT_VALUE
FROM
    cte
CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE (
    '/ROWSET/ROW'
    PASSING cte.XML
    COLUMNS CURRENT_VALUE number PATH '.'
)




ID
EVENT_ID
COLUMN_NAME
PREVIOUS_ENTRY
CURRENT_VALUE




1
1
LOCATIONID
35
50


1
2
PERSONID
1
3



with the result as a number, which is OK for these two values but not generically; you can change the data type from number to vachar2 in the XMLTable call. And if there might not be a current value you can use OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY.
Or more directly with XMLQuery:
SELECT
    sourceid AS ID,
    id AS EVENT_ID,
    key AS COLUMN_NAME,
    oldvalue AS PREVIOUS_ENTRY,
    XMLQUERY ('/ROWSET/ROW/*/text()'
        PASSING DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE (
            'select "' || key || '" from table1 where id = ' || sourceid)
        RETURNING CONTENT) AS CURRENT_VALUE
FROM
    AUDITTABLE




ID
EVENT_ID
COLUMN_NAME
PREVIOUS_ENTRY
CURRENT_VALUE




1
1
LOCATIONID
35
50


1
2
PERSONID
1
3



which returns the value as a string. You can convert that, but if it need to be generic, a string is probably your only option - as the current_value can't be more than one data type. That's going to potentially give you issues with dates etc. That would be true for a case expression too, of course, but at least then you could apply specific formatting for each key/column.
fiddle
PaulW's function approach might scale and perform better - not least because it allows the (hopefully PK) ID to be provided as a bind variable, reducing hard parsing (probably a lot).
A case expression might be more practical that either approach though, once created; and you can generate that from the data dictionary if you don't want to type it all. Presumably the audit table is being populated from a trigger, which would have the reverse problem, so you might be able to see how it was tackled there - including how triggers are generated and maintained.

Hi Alex!  This was actually precisely what I was looking for!  With the database I'm using, I can't execute DML or DDL, and am mostly limited to read-only privileges.  PaulW's solution would work, but I would need to loop in one of our developers to make the changes.  Your solution allowed me to get at the data directly, so thank you!
I ended up adding a: .getStringVal() to the end of the XMLQUERY, with a subquery within to pull the key as that was stored in the audit table, and it did the trick precisely.

This is what I went with:

SELECT
AUDITTABLE.sourceid AS ID,
AUDITTABLE.id AS EVENT_ID,
AUDITTABLE.key AS COLUMN_NAME,
AUDITTABLE.oldvalue AS PREVIOUS_ENTRY,
XMLQUERY ('/ROWSET/ROW/*/text()'
PASSING DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE (
'select "' || (select AT1.key from  AUDITTABLE as AT1 where AT1.id = audittable.id) || '" from TABLE where table.id = ' || audittable.sourceid)
RETURNING CONTENT).getStringVal() AS CURRENT_VALUE
FROM
AUDITTABLE


Clearly I have no idea how to format code blocks on here...

I'm not sure why you need the subquery - that appears to be finding the same row in the same table as the main query, and you already have the key value from that? (But yes, forgot to mention getstringval()...)

To make it generic you'll need to use dynamic SQL. The simplest way is a simple function that returns a value for a given table, row and column.
create or replace function current_value(in_table_name in varchar2,
                                         in_row_column in varchar2, 
                                         in_row_id in integer,
                                         in_select_column in varchar2)
  return varchar2
as
  var_result varchar2(4000);
begin
  execute immediate 'select max("'||in_select_column||'") 
                       from "'||in_table_name||'" 
                      where "'||in_row_column||'" = :id' 
               into var_result 
           using in in_row_id;

  return var_result;
end;

This will of course cast any column to a string, so if you need a date or number either reconvert it on output or create other functions or even packaged overloads to handle other datatypes. If all the columns you are tracking are numeric, then swap out the varchar2 for a number, otherwise using varchar2 is safest since most datatypes can be cast to it. It also clearly wouldn't handle a LOB and expects the row identifier to be numeric. Whatever complexity you need would need to be built-in, but this gives you the basic framework.
Also, to have any hope of decent performance, you'd want to ensure that the row identifying column (ID) is indexed in each table. If it's the PK it already should be. Then you simply query the audit table and call the function for each row:
SELECT
    sourceid AS ID,
    id AS EVENT_ID
    key AS COLUMN,
    oldvalue AS PREVIOUS_ENTRY,
    current_value('MYTABLE','ID',id,key) current_value
FROM AUDITTABLE  


Thank you Paul!  This is great information, and gives me an excellent starting point.

Not all columns of a table are of the same data type, columns may have their data type changed during the life of an application, etc. So if you want (previous_entry, current_value) they can only be the string representation of the data.
Another way of storing this audit data could be a JSON or XML payload, so you will have only 1 audit table (audit_pk, meta_pk, payload) for the whole schema and 1 audit meta data table (meta_pk, table name, version, meta_desc), the 1st one referencing the 2nd, the meta_desc containing a JSON or XML payload describing the metadata of the table for a particular version of its definition, metadata you can generate from the user_tab_columns each time you made change to the metadata of the table. And you will have only 1 row per original row modification instead of 1 row per column modified, and eventually it would be possible to have a polymorphic table function returning the modifications of a (table, version) as a row set (original pk, date_modif, col1_old_value, col1_new_value, ..., colN_old_value, colN_new_value) with each column being returned in its original data type, the PTF doing the conversion back from string to original data type thanks to the meta data... (that's where all the CASE for the different data types will be hidden...) and still have the possibility to return (column_name, old, new) triples using JSON_TABLE or XMLTABLE on the stored payload. Or having 1 VIEW per (table, version) to do the job of the PTF, so instead of 1 AUDITTABLE per TABLE, you will have 1 AUDITVIEW per TABLE... (should be possible to generate the code of the VIEWs based on user_tab_columns too).
